# jQuery Ajax query cancelled when link clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="page.html" onclick="loadAjax();">link</a>
```

page.html is verry long to load (due to a long process server-side).

The loadAjax function is like this:

```
function loadAjax() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.getJSON('otherPage.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                //do something
            });
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

But when I click the link, page.html is loading and Ajax query stops.
In Chrome's developper tool I see "canceled" next to otherPage.json.

So I have to load otherPage.json after loading of page.html starts because it get data modified by page.html's process.

Comment: why not do the whole thing in one? make page.html smaller and "instant-return" and load the rest of the data with `onLoad()`

Comment: yes, after loading it does.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You have a link to different page but then you have a setTimeout on the same link to do something very different

Comment: @JeevanJose Ajax query is made to test status updated by page.html process.

Comment: Actually, without setTimeout(), query appears to be cancelled. WITH setTimeout(), query does not appears in developper tool.

Comment: @Florent06 this is not really helpful. you shouldn't bother the server further when processing huge request. just refrain from checking the status, you just need it when it comes back (all the other times you will get "waiting" either way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed $.getJSON for $.ajax to add "async: false" and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

How it will work; on onlick your href attribute will take precedence and ajax call will stop.

Load the .html page after ajax call finished.

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadAjax();">link</a>
```

and in loadAjax() function, assign page dynamically to href attribute.

```
function loadAjax() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.getJSON('otherPage.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                //do something
            });
        });
    }, 2000);
    this.href="Page.html"
}
```

Use ref variable to this ( always a good practice)

Comment: this does not work. It does not change current page for page.html

Answer (score 1):

well if you click a link, and refer to a different page, all running requests for the current page are cancelled...

this is the expected and wanted behaviour (to prevent unnecessary loading).
if you need a simultaneous loading of two separate pages, you need 2 ajax requests. this means:

```
$('#htmlpagelink').click(function(){
   loadAjax(page.html);
   loadAjax(otherPage.json);
});

function loadAjax(url){
  /*  ...  code   ...   */
}
```

Careful, this does not change the current page, so if your user clicks a different link you gotta do it all over again.

instead you could speed up the first showing of results, by having your server return a comparably  small and thus fast html-page, that directly starts loading data from the server with exactly this construct. something like this should do the trick:

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>Page Title - loading...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).load(loadContent());

        function loadContent(){
            //see upper code-block
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="/loading.gif" alt="loading..." />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want otherPage to be loaded AFTER page.html but while its loading.

Comment: then start a double ajax request... imho the start of loading page.html as exclusive request (from the link) cancels the ajax request for otherPage.json. try loading both via ajax instead